# The best choice to implement custom deleter of shared_ptr, which is a class member

Tags: c++, opengl, shader

I am writing a little wrapper for OpenGL shaders. Each shader after creation receives ID from OpenGL. My Shader class keeps this ID and provides some useful stuff. My class should be copyable and movable.

In destructor of my class I want to call `glDeleteShader(m_rendererId)`. But I want to do it only for last copy of object of Shader class.

Example implementation of Shader class

```
class Shader
{
    public:
        Shader(ShaderType type, std::string shaderSource) { /*glCreateShader, glCompileShader*/ }
        ~Shader() { glDeleteShader(m_rendererId) }

    private:
        unsigned int m_rendererId = 0;
}
```

This implementation has a big problem. If I want to use one shader in multiply shader programs and I create one shader and make its copy, when one of them is destroyed, the `m_rendererId`  of other will point on removed by OpenGL shader object.

So my idea is to declare `m_rendererId` as follow:

```
std::shared_ptr<unsigned int> m_rendererId
```

I have 2 options to call `glDeleteShader(m_rendererId)` in this situation:

1. I can provide custom deleter, which will call `glDeleteShader(m_rendererId)`.
2. I can change destructor to the follow:

   ```
   ~Shader() {
       if (m_rendererId.use_count() == 1)
           glDeleteShader(m_rendererId);
   }
   ```

**So, what is the best choice to implement custom deleter of shared_ptr, which is a class member?**

Comment: You don't need to keep your shaders around after linking the program.

Comment: Why not just have `shared_ptr<Shader>`? That'd solve all of the ownership problems *and* it would make ownership clear to everyone who gets a `shared_ptr<Shader>`.

Comment: @tkausl, I can use one shader object in several shader programs. So, I want to create one Shader object and attach to several shader programs.

Comment: @NicolBolas , I've also thought about this, but it will restrict to use everywhere shared_ptr<Shader> and not just Shader, what can leads to situation, when I just create Shader object (not shared_ptr) and make a copy of its. With `std::shared_ptr<unsigned int> m_rendererId` I hide this ownership inside my class and not care about this in outside code.

Comment: I got that, but why do you need shared ownership, the linked programs don't need the shaders again, ever. So they don't need to keep a reference.

Comment: Yes, shader programs don't need to keep a reference on shader objects. But I'm creating a class for shader objects, which must keep shader object ID received from OpenGL. I also want to follow RAII and remove shader obj in destructor of Shader class. But I also want to make Shader class copyable and movable without risk of multiply call glDeleteShader with the same ID.

Comment: Note that `std::shared_ptr<unsigned int>` holds `unsigned int*`, not `unsigned int`. You could perhaps use `std::shared_ptr<void>` and cast between `unsigned int` and `void*`

Comment: You could trick `std::shared_ptr<void>` into doing reference counting and cleanup for you. Goes something like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/Kvvc6zczx)

Comment: If any object receives and owns an ID delivered by a third party (like OpenGL), then it is definitely NOT copyable.

Comment: Couldn't you make Shader non copyable? when creating a shaderprogram, instead of copying the Shader object, you just pass the rendererId, wouldn't that work?